# Change background image between iphone 4 and iphone 5 in storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, interface-builder

I have 2 background images built for the specific devices (320x480) and (640x960).
I have done the iphone 5 storyboards.

Now, how can I change the background image to the (320x480) version when viewed on a iphone 4?

Note auto layout wouldn't work for me in this case since it's not an alignment issue but rather the image itself.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer which solved your problem!

Answer (score 3):

Name 320x480 image "background.png"
Name 640x960 image "background@2x.png"
Name 640x568 image "background-568@2x.png"

then in story boar set background image to "background"

you can also set all these up in an assets.xcassets file in the same image set to simplify.

Comment: Do you mean -568h@2x? It says here in the comment that its only supported by launch images? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12517698/440646

Comment: @resting I think you're right.  568h@2x only for default image.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to detect iPhone 5 (widescreen devices)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446990/how-to-detect-iphone-5-widescreen-devices)

Simply set the image in viewDidLoad after you've checked the device

Answer (score 1):

I always include these `macros` inside my `.pch` file:

```
#define isiPad  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 1024)?TRUE:FALSE
#define isiPhone4  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480)?TRUE:FALSE
#define isiPhone5  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)?TRUE:FALSE
```

So you can create a switch and set the specific `UIImage` you need for the screen. I also created a [`gist` with some more useful `marc`](http://bit.ly/macrosIos)